# create multiple pivot table in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have successfully created a pivot table by using VBA, but now I would like to create two pivot tables in two separate worksheets, 2 and 3.  But my scripted VBA only creates one pivot table, even though I already set 2 Pivot table variables: PT1 and PT2, and 2 pivot cache variables: PTCache1 and PTCache2.  The raw data is in worksheet 1, which I set as RawData.
Below is my script.  Please help me out what I am missing here.  Thanks.

```
Private Sub CreatePivotTables()
Dim ReportC2 As Workbook, RawData As Worksheet, SanityA As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, i As Long
Dim PTCache1 As PivotCache, PTCache2 As PivotCache, PT1 As PivotTable, PT2 As PivotTable

Set ReportC2 = Workbooks.Open(ScorecardAddr & "\" & C2Name)
Set RawData = ReportC2.ActiveSheet

With RawData
    Columns("A:A").Insert
    .Range("A1").Value = "Deal & SKU"
    LastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


    For i = 2 To LastRow
        .Range("A" & i) = .Range("F" & i).Value & "|" & .Range("P" & i).Value
    Next

End With

With RawData

    Set PTCache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)))
    Set PTCache2 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)))
End With

On Error Resume Next
With ReportC2

.Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count), Count:=2
.Sheets(2).Name = "C2Pivot-Transactional"

    Set PT1 = .Sheets(2).PivotTables.Add(PTCache1, Range("A7"), "C2PT1")

    'put the fields in the pivot table
    With PT1
        .PivotFields("Deal & SKU").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("quantity").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("GrossSellto").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("Total BDD Rebate").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("Total FLCP Rebate").Orientation = xlDataField
    End With
End With

With ReportC2

    .Sheets(3).Name = "C2Pivot-Reseller"

    Set PT2 = .Sheets(3).PivotTables.Add(PTCache2, Range("A7"), "C2PT2")

    'put the fields in the pivot table
    With PT2
        .PivotFields("Reseller ID").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("GrossSellto").Orientation = xlDataField
        .CalculatedFields.Add "BDD + FLCP", "= 'Total BDD Rebate' + 'Total FLCP Rebate'"
        .PivotFields("BDD + FLCP").Orientation = xlDataField
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You should remove the On Error Goto Next and see what error you get.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `Set PTCache2...` and only using PTCache1 for both pivot tables?

Comment: @BobPhillips Unfortunately I am a Noob for Excel VBA, the error message means not much to me.  These codes are actually what I found in YouTube with some minor adjustment to suit my data set.  Thanks.

Comment: Tell us what the error says, and on what line, maybe we can help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try not using the `.Select` rather try to explicitly refernce your workbooks and sheets. Because of this you'r pivottables both get added at `Range("A7")`, so on the same place. Try referencing to start with WB.WS.Range, where WB is a variable that stores your workbook and WS a variable that stores your WS.

Edit: as a reference, here a question, and answers, on how to avoid using `.Select`: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Edit2:
Fixed your code(hopefully)

Edit3: Add-back with...end with, and put the two pivotcaches in the With loop, also remove PT2 variable as duplicate, and lastly merge the "With ReportC2 between the two PT table addon.  And it works.

```
Private Sub CreatePivotTables()
Dim ReportC2 As Workbook, RawData As Worksheet, SanityA As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, i As Long
Dim PTCache1 As PivotCache, PTCache2 As PivotCache, PT As PivotTable

Set ReportC2 = Workbooks.Open(ScorecardAddr & "\" & C2Name)
Set RawData = ReportC2.Worksheets(1)

With RawData
    Columns("A:A").Insert
    .Range("A1").Value = "Deal & SKU"
    LastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


    For i = 2 To LastRow
        .Range("A" & i) = .Range("F" & i).Value & "|" & .Range("P" & i).Value
Next

End With
with RawData
    Set PTCache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)))
    Set PTCache2 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)))
End With

On Error Resume Next
With ReportC2

.Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count), Count:=2
.Sheets(2).Name = "C2Pivot-Transactional"

    Set PT = .Sheets(2).PivotTables.Add(PTCache1, Worksheets(2).Range("A7"), "C2PT1")

    'put the fields in the pivot table
    With PT
        .PivotFields("Deal & SKU").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("quantity").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("GrossSellto").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("Total BDD Rebate").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("Total FLCP Rebate").Orientation = xlDataField
    End With

    .Sheets(3).Name = "C2Pivot-Reseller"

    Set PT2 = .Sheets(3).PivotTables.Add(PTCache2, Worksheets(3).Range("A7"), "C2PT2")

    'put the fields in the pivot table
    With PT2
        .PivotFields("Reseller ID").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("GrossSellto").Orientation = xlDataField
        .CalculatedFields.Add "BDD + FLCP", "= 'Total BDD Rebate' + 'Total FLCP Rebate'"
        .PivotFields("BDD + FLCP").Orientation = xlDataField
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I tried.  I substitute RawData which denotes "ReportC2.ActiveSheet"; and use With ... End With, but still failed.  What's wrong with my code?  Thanks.

Comment: @lukayl I made the changes for you, let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @Luuklag, the first try gave me error, seems RawData.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))) doesn't work.  So I still add on the With RawData, ... End With loop in the two PivotCaches sections, then use ActiveWorkbook instead of RawData within the With Loop.  Remove additional PT2 variable as I found one PT is good as well.  Then merge two With ReportC2 loops in the Pivot Table sections into one to avoid clanky.  And it all works.  Thanks.

Comment: I bet you could also do with only one PTCache, as they are both of the same range.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on assumed data. I ditched PTCache2, one is sufficient for the same source.

```
Private Sub CreatePivotTables()
Dim ReportC2 As Workbook, RawData As Worksheet, SanityA As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, i As Long
Dim PTCache1 As PivotCache, PT As PivotTable, Pt2 As PivotTable

    Set ReportC2 = ActiveWorkbook 'Workbooks.Open(ScorecardAddr & "\" & C2Name)
    Set RawData = ReportC2.Worksheets(1)

    With RawData

        .Columns("A:A").Insert
        .Range("A1").Value = "Deal & SKU"
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


        For i = 2 To LastRow
            .Range("A" & i) = .Range("F" & i).Value & "|" & .Range("P" & i).Value
        Next

        Set PTCache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)))
    End With

    With ReportC2

    .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count), Count:=2
    .Sheets(2).Name = "C2Pivot-Transactional"

        Set PT = .Sheets(2).PivotTables.Add(PTCache1, Worksheets(2).Range("A7"), "C2PT1")

        'put the fields in the pivot table
        With PT
            .PivotFields("Deal & SKU").Orientation = xlRowField
            .PivotFields("quantity").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("GrossSellto").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("Total BDD Rebate").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("Total FLCP Rebate").Orientation = xlDataField
        End With

        .Sheets(3).Name = "C2Pivot-Reseller"

        Set Pt2 = .Sheets(3).PivotTables.Add(PTCache1, Worksheets(3).Range("A7"), "C2PT2")

        'put the fields in the pivot table
        With Pt2
            .PivotFields("Reseller ID").Orientation = xlRowField
            .PivotFields("GrossSellto").Orientation = xlDataField
            .CalculatedFields.Add "BDD + FLCP", "= 'Total BDD Rebate' + 'Total FLCP Rebate'"
            .PivotFields("BDD + FLCP").Orientation = xlDataField
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```